# How to write a test that tests that AutoMapper is called with the correct operation options

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, automapper, nsubstitute

I have this piece of code and want to test that `opts.Items["foo"]` is set correctly.

```
public Result DoStuff(MyInput myObj)
{
    var mapped = _mapper.Map<Result>(myObj,
        opts =>
        {
            opts.Items["foo"] = "bar";
        });
    return mapped;
}
```

And my test looks like this

```
public void MapperShouldBeCalledWithCorrectOperationItems()
{
    // Arrange
    var optObj = Substitute.For<IMappingOperationOptions>();
    Action<IMappingOperationOptions> argumentUsed = null;
    _mapper.Received().Map<Result>(result, Arg.Do<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(arg => argumentUsed = arg));

    // Act
    _uut.DoStuff(new MyInput());
    argumentUsed.Invoke(optObj);

    // Assert
    optObj.Items["foo"].Should().Be("bar");
}
```

Now this doesn't work and I'm not even sure I'm on the right path :(

I don't think I can inspect the lambda so I instead have to check that `IMappingOperationOptions` have `Items["foo"]` set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly method that you want to test looks like? I mean your first code is not a method, just block of code.

Comment: @Evk edited post, hopefully it makes it a bit more clear

Comment: But you don't pass your substituted mapper to `_uut` class. So it just uses regular `_mapper`.

Comment: Oh good catch. That's some bad example code. It does that in real code. Fixing...

Comment: Not related, but isn't so, that you shouldn't test how mapping is implemented - instead test that return value is equivalent to expected?

Comment: @Fabio Valid point. But figuring out why the mapping didn't work could be troublesome. With a test like this I can give a clear error message stating that the developer forgot to send the correct item.

Comment: @Good reason, but worth to mention, that testing implementation details,will make tests fragile when you doing some refactoring. Possible not related to your case...

Comment: Another approach - if you have complex types - to have one test for every property/value - then you will get specific failing message in the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
public void MapperShouldBeCalledWithCorrectOperationItems()
{
    // Arrange
    var optObj = Substitute.For<IMappingOperationOptions>();

    Action<IMappingOperationOptions> argumentUsed = null;
    _mapper
        .Map<Result>(Arg.Any<Result>,
                     Arg.Do<Action<IMappingOperationOptions>>(arg => argumentUsed = arg));

    // Act
    _uut.DoStuff(new MyInput());
    argumentUsed.Invoke(optObj);

    // Assert
    optObj.Items["foo"].Should().Be("bar");
}
```